# Remove empty lines and spaces in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Suppose I have these lines:

```
A

B

C

D

E
```

I want remove empty lines, and the spaces before the letter too, like this:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

How can I achieve this in Notepad++?

Comment: no idea, perfectly fine question imo. btw can you check if the formatting is correct for your spaces. Is there meant to be four spaces before a character (if so, add 4 more per line so the site's formatting takes this into account)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

To get rid of leading space(s) and all empty lines (even if the empty line contains spaces or tabs)

1. Go to **Search -> Replace**
2. Select "Regular expression" under **Search mode**.
3. Use `^\s*` for "**Find what**" and leave "**Replace with**" blank.
4. Click <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Regex explanation:

- `^` means beginning of the line
- `\s*` means any number (even 0) of whitespace characters. Whitespace characters include tab, space, newline, and carriage return.

Comment: What would you search for to remove trailing white spaces if ^\s* is beginning of line?

Comment: An alternativeo to `\s*` would be `\s+` for one or more white spaces?

Comment: @Aaron: Search for `\s+$` to remove trailing whitespace.

Comment: -1 This also deletes the indent

Answer (score 48):

*Edit* -> *Line Operations* -> *Remove Empty Lines* or alternatively: *Edit* -> *Line Operations* -> *Remove Empty Lines (Containing Blank characters)*

[image]

Comment: So cool! I never noticed there is so many edit options in Edit menu. Thanks!

Comment: This is what most people are looking for when then come to StackOverflow for this question, unfortunately the "\r\n" and "^\s*" answers are "Cooler", takes me 5 minutes to find this answer with Google. Those other answers are kind of self explanatory (with a little knowledge of regular expressions and escape chars), this in the one that actually saves you time...

Answer (score 8):

Go to `Edit` > `Line Operations` > `Remove Empty Lines`

Comment: No reason to downvote this. It is a perfectly valid answer.

Answer (score 6):

The easy way would be select everything (Ctrl+A), go to Edit>Blank Operation>Trim Trailing Space.

This should remove all the spaces in between.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple regular expression search and replace.

1. Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for the *Replace* dialog
2. Make sure you select 'Regular expression' option
3. Find what: `____(.)\r_` **(swap _ with space, as it doesn't format right on this site)**
4. Replace with: `\1`

Change the spaces as you need because I think this site is not showing the exact spaces you need.

[image: Find and Replace dialog in Notepad++]

I recommend tailor making your regular expression using [this tutorial](http://markantoniou.blogspot.hu/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html) and this [cheat sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v2.png).

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open Find and Replace dialog Box, and enter like below.

1. Type **\r\n\r\n** in *Find what*
2. Type **\r\n** in *Replace with*
3. Select **Extended** in *Search Mode*
   [\r -> Carriage Return & \n ->Line Feed]
   It will even removes uneven line spaces.Just continue clicking **REPLACE ALL** till you attain the expected result. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Copy 2 blank spaces (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>), search and replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>), paste in the Find field and select Replace. If you have the same character with a blank space behind or in front, copy the character with the blank and replace it with the same character without the blank.

No complicated commands, which, by the way, didn't work for me.

Comment: This sound like removing spaces, not line feeds.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Edit > Blank Operations > Remove Unnecessary Blank and EOL

Comment: -1. This places everything in a single line.